# Javascript Object context

Tags: javascript

Do this Object have its context:

```
{}
```

if yes ,than it must also have VO(Variable Object) .So than,when i do this:

```
foo={
    name:"Maizere",
    height:function () {console.log(name);}//output is undefined
 }

  foo.height();
```

When the height() method gets run js first checks function context since it can't find that name ,it travels to next i.e parent context Vo and here parent context is the context of literal object ,since that name resides in that VO why i get undefined?

How is that property residing in the VO of the literal object context simply as a property or simply like variable ,i need a complete explanation .Thank u @all.

Comment: When you're within the `Object` you have to reference the `parent` or `self` in-order to access the `methods`, so it would be: `console.log(this.name);` [more information can be found over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the call context (with the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) with the *variable scope*, and with object properties.

To answer your question: **No**, objects do not have a scope. Only functions have a scope attribute, which will initialise the scope chain of their variable object when they get called. Since there are no variables with the name `name` in the scope of your `height` function, it resolves to `undefined` (or even a Reference Error).

Answer (score 2):

An object member is referenced through the current object using `this`:

```
height: function() { console.log( this.name ); }
//                                ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the `this` keyword and you have a small *SyntaxError* on the *name* line (you wanted a `,` but wrote `;`).

```
var foo = {
        name: "Maizere",
        height: function () {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    };

foo.height(); // "Maizere"
```